# binary search tree parent pointer

Tags: java, parent-child, binary-search-tree

Im writing a binary search tree and i want to include a parent pointer. The way I have it now is that the parent reference is a node. so for example my getParent() returns a node rather than a value.

my question is if this is the right way to do so or if the parent reference should just be to the value of the parent so that getParent() would return a value instead of a node?

Comment: It should be the node and it should be of internal usage on the tree.

Comment: Yeah it should be node for sure. If it was value, then you'd have to search for the appropriate node when getting a parent by value. That is.. Assuming you will ever need to traverse the tree in reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend returning the node itself. If you keep storing the values themselves, the data size will get unreasonably large, almost double theoretically in fact, since each node would contain two sets of values instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirement but it seems like you are doing it right keeping it as Node with Nodevalue.
This way if needed you can enhance your program to say include orientation if needed. 
It is more flexible this way.